# Opening a unique text file based on a random number

Tags: python, file, text, random

Opening a unique text file in Python based on a random number.

I'm using a random number generator to randomly open a text file, however my code will consist of a lot of if statements because I'm rather new and its the only way I know how. But there is a better way, because theres a better way in every programming language, I just need to know what it is. 
Heres my code:

```
n = random.randint(1, 3)
    print n
    if (n == 1):
         f = open('E:/1.txt', 'r')
```

I would obviously have to do this for every random number generated, so how can I...

```
f = open('E:/' & n & '.txt., 'r')
```

That obviously doesn't work, but hopefully you get the idea and can give me a hand.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use string formatting:

```
n = random.randint(1, 3)
f = open('E:/%d.txt' % n, 'r')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(3):
    n = random.randint(1,3)
    with open("E:\{0}.txt".format(n),"r") as f:
        #do something
```

Comment: then the file didnt exist ... "r" means open to read so the file must exist or it will raise an error

Answer (score 0):

In python you use the `str` function to convert an integer to a string and the `+` operator to concatenate strings together.

```
n = random.randint(1, 3)
f = open('E:/' + str(n) + '.txt', 'r')
```

It would probably be better to use [String Formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) though to get what you're looking for.

```
n = random.randint(1, 3)
f = open('E:/%s.txt' % n, 'r')
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly, exactly what I needed. I forgot about string conversion!

Comment: @user1690054, glad to hear it worked. FYI, its considered 'good behavior' to upvote and/or accept an answer (click the check box on the left), if it helped you. Cheers.